# find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }I_n$, $I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{1+nx}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

given $f(x)$ an integrable function on $[0,1]$, find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }I_n$

when $I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{1+nx}dx$

Intuitively I'm pretty sure the answer is 0 because f is bounded so i thought about something like:

$$|I_n|=|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{1+nx}dx|\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{|f(x)|}{1+nx}dx\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{M}{1+nx}dx$$
$$=\lim_{\lambda(p)\rightarrow 0}someRiemannSum$$

But it doesn't seem to work out for me. Any ideas?

*I know a similar question has been asked but the answers there didn't help me...

Comment: The last integral equals $(1/n)\log(1+n)\to 0$ so desired limit is $0$.

Comment: Integrable doesn't imply bounded. Take $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh But this is real analysis not computer science, how do I prove it?

Comment: @Joe Riemann integrable means bounded...

Comment: That comment is a proof. And I don't see how computer science comes into picture.

Comment: @Joe: Riemann integrable functions are by definition bounded. Your example of $x^{-1/2}$ is about improper Riemann integration.

Comment: You're right. But the tag is "real analysis" which deals with Lebesgue integral (so even more general than improper Riemann integral), more than Riemann integral.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh saying the integral equals to (1/n)log(1+n)→0 is not a proof, as I have no idea for how to prove it, and we did not see this identity in class.

Comment: if you could elaborate on how to show that this is the case it would be great.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I guess He means that $(1/n) \log (1+n) \rightarrow 0$ is from $1/n = o(\log n)$(small Oh notation) hence he thought that this is Computer Science way of proving and what he is saying is that he wants $\epsilon-\delta$ proof

Comment: @viru that is exactly what I mean

Comment: just to clarify, I want to see why the last integral equals (1/n)log(1+n)→0

Comment: @reggiN actually the Paramanand Singh proof is rigorous, because it uses squeeze theorem since $|I_n| \geq 0$; you don't always have to rely on $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof when you can use a simplier way to prove something.
And you must be able to find an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof from the fact that $\frac{M \ln (n+1)}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
I find your comment about computer science a little inappropriate.

Comment: @Dunklheit I didn't mean anything inappropriate, it's just not a proof. Look at QC_QAOA's answer to see what my intention was, I can't rely on limit identities you may think of as obvious as proof.

Comment: As an aside, if by "integrable" the question had meant "Lebesgue integrable" then the dominated convergence theorem would apply.

Comment: Just to clarify I thought that evaluation of the integral was obvious for you. The evaluation is not difficult based on standard formula $\int \frac{dx} {x} =\log x+C$. I am sure you must have encountered this in your introductory calculus course. One should have the integrals for basic elementary functions readily available in memory. Anyway since you have accepted an answer it suggests that issue is resolved to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+nx}dx=\int_0^n\frac{1}{1+y}\frac{dy}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\int_1^{n+1}\frac{1}{z}dz=\frac{1}{n}[\ln(n+1)-\ln(1)]=\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n}$$

which comes from the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: great, care to explain the first equality? It makes sense to me but I'm not sure what's the formal explanation for it.

Comment: @reggiN substitute $nx=y$.

Answer (score 1):

I am just repeating what @Paramanand Singh said and giving it full proof.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_n = 0$$ implies we have to show that 
 $$\forall \epsilon >0 \,\, \exists N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N} \,\, \forall n \geq N : |I_n| < \epsilon$$
and note that $I_n = \frac{\log(1+n) - \log(1)}{n} = \frac{\log (1+n)}{n}$ because $\int \frac{1}{1+nx} =  \frac{\log(1+nx)}{n}$ and rest goes as follows

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log (1+n)}{n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1+n}  = 0$$ equality comes for L'hospital rule and if you are  precisely looking for $N_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$  suffices because $\frac{1}{1+n} \leq \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$

Comment: thanks but this is not the part i have trouble with. how do we show the last integral is equal to this limit?

Comment: @reggiN Does that help or do you want more clarification ?